# Why is TestCafe crashing on launch testing Electron app with simple command-line?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, electron, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am attempting to run a test on our Electron app using TestCafe. I am getting an error mentioning a "-m" command, however that is not used in my script or command line.

I have everything set up as described here:
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-electron#testing-an-executable-electron-application

> C:\packages>**testcafe -d "electron:C:\Program Files\OurApp\"
>   "C:\Temp\test.js" -hostname localhost**
>
> Using locally installed version
>   of TestCafe. ERROR Tested app failed with an error:
>
> Error: Command failed: -m '-m' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
> at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
> at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
> at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
> at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:557:12)
> ```
>
> Type "testcafe -h" for help.

The script for test.js is below:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Electron test`
.page('./index.html');

test('smoke 1', async t => {
await t
.debug() 
.click(Selector().withText('Create a new configuration'));
});
```

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause is in an incorrect `-hostname` argument. It should be `--hostname`. I'm not sure why some `-m` error appears but tests work after I fix incorrect argument syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I would never have figured that out